# When I try to login using AWS Cognito I get an AccessDeniedException about my custom Lambda trigger

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am calling adminInitiateAuth and getting back a strange AccessDeniedException for my own lambdas.

Here is the code I'm calling:

```
      var params = {
        AuthFlow: "ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH",
        ClientId: "@cognito_client_id@",
        UserPoolId: "@cognito_pool_id@",
        AuthParameters: {
          USERNAME : username,
          PASSWORD : tempPassword
        },
      };
      cognitoIdentityServiceProvider.adminInitiateAuth(params, function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
          console.log("ERROR! Login failed: " + JSON.stringify(error), error.stack);
        } else {
          console.log("Login sent back: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        }
      });
```

The error message I'm getting is:

```
ERROR! Login failed: {"message":"arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:201473124518:function:main-devryan-users_onCognitoLogin failed with error AccessDeniedException.","code":"UnexpectedLambdaException","time":"2017-02-25T18:54:15.109Z","requestId":"ce42833f-fb8b-11e6-929b-2f78b63faa12","statusCode":400,"retryable":false,"retryDelay":1.0853444458916783} UnexpectedLambdaException: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:201473124518:function:main-devryan-users_onCognitoLogin failed with error AccessDeniedException.
```

Does anybody know why I might be getting this error?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

This was happening because I recreated my API Gateway & Lambdas (using serverless) and it turns out that the Cognito console sneakily adds permissions to contact a given Lambda function when added as a trigger through the console.

---

**To fix this in your CloudFormation / serverless.yml file**:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    OnCognitoSignupPermission:
      Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Permission'
      Properties:
        Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
        FunctionName:
          Fn::GetAtt: [ "UsersUnderscoreonCognitoSignupLambdaFunction", "Arn"]
        Principal: "cognito-idp.amazonaws.com"
        SourceArn:
          Fn::Join: [ "", [ "arn:aws:cognito-idp", ":", Ref: "AWS::Region", ":", Ref: "AWS::AccountId", ":", "userpool/", "@cognito_pool_id@" ] ]
```

---

**To fix this in the AWS console**:

- Go to the Cognito Console
- Choose your user pool
- Go to "Triggers"
- Remove your custom trigger (set it to None) and click "Save"
- Now reset it back and click "Save" again

Here's [an interesting Amazon forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=748566&#748566) that led me down the right track.

Comment: This is crazy. Also, the drift detection feature for Cloud Formation templates cannot see any difference after re-saving the trigger.

Comment: I updated my answer to include the changes we made to get it working in CloudFormation.  Kudos to @shanewwarren's answer below (although honestly we'd figured it out a few months before he posted his answer).

Comment: If anybody else is setting Cognito up using Terraform, there's an [open issue around the lambda permissions](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/8373).

Comment: @the0ther I wonder if AWS scans Stack Overflow with sentiment analysis and picks up comments like ours. :)

Comment: Hey you all, I get this error after deploying the cloud formation with amplify-cli, I have tried to add this kind of permission all sorts of places and in many other formats as well, they never where deployed. does anyone know in which cloud formation template and where exactly should this permission be placed to be deployed successfully ?

Comment: @DavidBenAri I guess you don't care anymore, but for other people struggling to figure out where to place this permission, you put it on same indentation as your congito pool right after the cognito pool definition.

Answer (score 40):

I had a problem similar to yours except I was trying to configure the Lambda with my Cognito User Pool through CloudFormation.

In the link that Ryan had posted there was a code sample someone posted.  Namely Cognito needed the proper permissions to invoke the lambda function.

```
MyLambdaInvocationPermission:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  Properties:
    Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
    FunctionName: !GetAtt MyLambdaFunctionName.Arn
    Principal: cognito-idp.amazonaws.com
    SourceArn: !GetAtt MyCognitoUserPoolName.Arn
```

Comment: Thanks, Saved my Day !

Comment: Thanks, this was what was missing.

Comment: Worked like charm,...Thank you

Comment: Yup it took me ages to get to the same conclusion. Just add the permission under `Resources`. I set the SourceArn to `arn:aws:cognito-idp:<your region>:<your account>:userpool/*` so as to give access to all our pools.

Comment: Hey you all, I get this error after deploying the cloud formation with amplify-cli, I have tried to add this kind of permission all sorts of places and in many other formats as well, they never where deployed. does anyone know in which cloud formation template and where exactly should this permission be placed to be deployed successfully ?

Comment: You sir are nothing short of a gee nee uss.
Just to add I used FunctionName: "my-function-name" without the .Arn

Comment: Still relevant. The documentation is really confusing around Cognito triggers. thanks!

Answer (score 34):

For someone ending up here, trying to add cognito triggers via terraform, all you need to do is to add an aws_lambda_permission resource:

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_execution_from_user_pool" {
  statement_id = "AllowExecutionFromUserPool"
  action = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.<lambda>.function_name
  principal = "cognito-idp.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn = aws_cognito_user_pool.<pool>.arn
}
```

Found in this great post: https://www.integralist.co.uk/posts/cognito/

Answer (score 1):

#### while creation of cloudformation stack - I got error like

```
User:arn:aws::12345678:user/xyz is not authorized to perform:
cognito-idp:CreateUserPool on resource:*(Service:AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService;
Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException;Request ID: xxxxx)
```

#### workaround :

- went on to the Stack which is in Rollback state -> checked events and could see , (creation-failed) some Roles I don't have access ,
- So , I checked IAM policy assigned to me - I was not having the access.
- I created a new policy and assigned to myself as an Inline Policy by Importing it from AWS.

  > aws-cognito-idp

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Cognito-IDP",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:InvokeFunction",
                "cognito-idp:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

> note: you can restrict the access on resource and cognito-idp user.

with this - I am successfully able to create and deploy cloudformation Stack for the module.

Comment: This error is completely unrelated to the OP - it indicates that the user running cloudformation does not have access to create the Cognito User Pool.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the permission  from the lambda Role (create a policy for cognito and add to to the lamda role ) . this solve my problem when i stuck into it